# Flask server not working with configparser as a database

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, configparser

```py
#error to fix in here
@application.route('/requestid', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def requestid():
    print("Part requestid")
    key = request.args.get('key')
    id = request.args.get('id')
    apikey = "thisisthekey"
    print(id)
    print(key)
    if key == apikey:
        print("key was correct")
        config['useridsincheck'][id] = 'waiting'
        with open('database.ini', 'w') as configfile:
            config.write(configfile)
        return 'succsess'
    else:
        print("key was wrong")
        return 'wrong key'
```

When I try running this I get this error:

```
    config['useridsincheck'][str(id)] = 'waiting'
  File "C:\Python\Python38\Lib\configparser.py", line 960, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'useridsincheck'
```

The config:

```
[info]
servername = crackers
members = 10
guildid = 919201778816397334

[users]
test = test

[useridsincheck]
test2 = test2

[test]
```

I am trying to make a API for a discord application combined with config parser as a database. If anyone can help thanks.

Comment: Post the ini file ad well

Comment: Sure. I added it

Comment: @baldman I added it

Comment: Where config is defined? We can't see it in the code you have posted